# Is there a java library that validates a multicast address?

Tags: java, multicast

I have used InetAddressValidator function for checking a valid IP address in Java but I'm looking for something that specifically checks a multicast address.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InetAddress` class has two subclasses, `Inet4Address` and `Inet6Address`, which are for IPv4 and IPv6 addresses respectively.

Both subclasses define a `isMulticastAddress()` method which returns true if the address is a multicast address.

Comment: Thank you very much this is quite helpful.

Comment: @TKPhillyBurb Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

[The open-source IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) will do this in a polymorphic manner for both IPv4 and IPv6 and handles a wide variety of address and subnet formats including CIDR formats.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of that library.

Example code:

```
isMulticast("224.0.0.0/4");
isMulticast("ff00::/64");
isMulticast("224-239.0.0.1-5");
isMulticast("1.0.0.0/4");
isMulticast("fe::/64");

static void isMulticast(String addressStr) {
    IPAddressString addrString = new IPAddressString(addressStr);
    IPAddress addr = addrString.getAddress();
    boolean result = addr.isMulticast();
    System.out.println(addr +  " is multicast " + result);
}
```

Output:

```
224.0.0.0/4 is multicast true
ff00::/64 is multicast true
224-239.0.0.1-5 is multicast true
1.0.0.0/4 is multicast false
fe::/64 is multicast false
```